# Understanding privilege escalation in ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm new to ansible and I've been playing with privilege escalation but I'm a little confused about how it works, if I were to define a task as

```
- name: Do something
  become: yes
  command: some command
```

I will execute this task while logged in as the root user but what if I don't want that and just want it to behave like **sudo some command** on the remote machine while still logged in as the current user, is it as simple as writing it out like this

```
- name: Do something
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  command: some command
```

or do I have to use the lines above with **become_user: {{ ansible_user }}**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible always logs to target ssh server as remote_user.
If you use `become: yes` Ansible calls `sudo` (or other privilege escalation tool) to run command as `become_user`.

If you execute Ansible with `-vvv` verbosity, you will see that it do exactly what you want: log in as current user, then `sudo command`.

The only thing is that Ansible uses python-wrappers for command execution, and if you need to execute exactly `sudo some command` without any wrappers, you can use:

```
- name: Do something
  become: yes
  raw: some command
```